# Waiting for a CSS property to be set with js before moving on.

Tags: javascript, css

Consider this JS function:

```
function myFunc() {

  const date = new Date();
  const secs = date.getSeconds();
  const secDeg = 360*(secs / 60)+ 90 ;

  hand.style.transitionDuration = '0s';
  hand.style.transform = `rotate(${secDeg}deg)`;
  hand.style.transitionDuration = '2s';
}
```

I would expect the rotation to be done with the transition of 0 seconds. However, it uses the value '2s' even though it is set after the rotation. Is this because `rotate()` takes too long to complete? How do I deal with this? I guess I could do it with the `transitionend` event listener but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called to fast, so its overwriting the timer in that time ;) So yes using a delay or a event end would be best.

(If you have jquery)

```
function myFunc() {

  const date = new Date();
  const secs = date.getSeconds();
  const secDeg = 360*(secs / 60)+ 90 ;

  hand.style.transitionDuration = '0s';
  hand.style.transform = `rotate(${secDeg}deg)`;
  $(hand).one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
              function(event) {
                  hand.style.transitionDuration = '2s';
  });
}
```

Comment: A different option is to use jquery animate function, it has a callback when it is complete. 

http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Or (plugin) http://jqueryrotate.com/

Comment: It seems that when I set transitionDuration to 0 I am not able to listen to the 'transitionend' event :/ . As in, even though rotation occurs, 'transitionend' does not fire, because transitionDuration is zero. Had to use setTimeout which I don't really like.